# Getting issue to hide responsive menu sidebar click outside anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bigcommerce

here is website link https://machinetoolproducts.com/

I have a big commerce website, in responsive need to hide menu if users will click outside into page anywhere.

There are already many solutions in StackOverflow but unfortunately, it does not work for me. I know this is duplicate questions but I have tested many scripts.but it's not going to resolve the issue when I click on the menu there is going to add a class with "on-screen" and when click on the menu again the class going to add "off-screen". The main problem is that when I removed the class with the help of jquery "on-screen" its look like this  http://prntscr.com/f6x66x .

it means to say that jquery working fine but I don't know why menu not completely going to hide.

it needs to hide completely if clicked outside.

here are the code sections

topmenu.html

```
<div class="TopMenu-mobile hidden-desktop hidden-tablet wow fadeInUp">
    <div class="menu-mobile">
        <div id="ToggleMenu"> menu </div>
 </div>
```

The above code id="ToggleMenu"  target to drawer menu.html

drawermenu.html

```
%%GLOBAL_OptimizerLinkScript%%
<div id="DrawerMenu">
    <div class="inner">
        <ul class="sf-menu sf-horizontal"><li><a href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%">Home</a></li></ul>
        %%Panel.SideCategoryList%% 
    </div>
</div>
%%Panel.DrawerMenuJavascript%%
%%Panel.HL_Megamenu%%
%%Panel.HL-MegamenuJS%%
```

please provide suggestion to me

Answer (score 0):

By checking your code, when you click on the hamburger to collapse your menu, it seems to happen 2 things :

The class on-screen appears on `<div id=DrawerMenu class="on-screen">` and the class off-screen appears on `<div class="page HL-NoCurrency off-screen">`

If you just remove the on-screen of your DrawerMenu, you will have the visual bug you show on your screenshot, so you need to be careful to remove also the `off-screen` class of the other div when you modify it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you mean to say that I need to remove off-screen too?  I have checked it to the menus going to hide but the white space still stays there.

Comment: In my browser, it seems that on-click, it just inverts the value : if you have an argument, it will disable it by clicking and if there is not, it will enable it. The thing I think would be better is to make sure the `off-screen` and `on-screen` classes are there at the same time. You can try by your browser to remove only one of two to see what happens (you should get the same graphic issue as in your screenshot)

Comment: Yes, you are right, it mean the removeClass is working but any idea to how can be same time the three lines menu back to their old positions, when one of the classes going to removed on click to outside.? This is the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have resolved my problem,  as I was said that the jquery is working fine but div structure going to bad so I have to make div like below:

```
<div class="menu-mobile">
        <div id="ToggleMenu"> menu </div>

       %%GLOBAL_OptimizerLinkScript%%
       <div id="DrawerMenu">
       <div class="inner">
        <ul class="sf-menu sf-horizontal"><li><a href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%">Home</a></li></ul>
        %%Panel.SideCategoryList%%    
       </div>
       </div>
       %%Panel.DrawerMenuJavascript%%
       %%Panel.HL_Megamenu%%
       %%Panel.HL-MegamenuJS%%  
    </div>
```

and then disable the class on-screen when clicking outside

```
<script>  
 $(document).on("click", function(e) { 
    if ($(e.target).is("#ToggleMenu") === false) {
    $("#DrawerMenu").removeClass("on-screen");
    }
  });
</script>
```